# Hybris ecommerce add product to cart via querystring

Tags: web-services, e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

It is possible to add a product to cart via a query string ?

How can I do that if it's possible?

Comment: Why is this not in the forum btw?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it out of the box using Omni Commerce Connected (OCC) commerce API (see [documentation for cart](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Resource+Cart)):

For example :

**URL** : `https://localhost:9002/rest/v1/electronics/cart/entry`

**Parameters (query string)** : `code=3429337`

**Result** : Adds product with code=3429337 to the cart

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Are you using the Accelerator? Add a method to a new or existing Controller that accepts a product code as a request  parameter (`@RequestParam`) and uses a Facade to add the product. The actual Facade  implementation is looking up the session cart, looking up the Product via FlexSearch (or through a Service), then adding the Product to Cart. You can look at the existing add to cart functionality to get a start. The main thing of creating a method to accept the query string is an exercise in Spring MVC.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I'm using the Accelerator yes; I don't know how to add a method to the "Cart Controller" (it's my firt contact with Hybris), is that a necessary point to do that task ?

Comment: Yes. Are thinking something along the lines of `<a href="http://yourdomain.com/site/cart/add?productCode=ASDF123">Add ASDF123 to cart</a>`?

Comment: Yes, coz you want to do a GET in order to change the resource. Coz that doesn't break everything at all...

Comment: The better solution would be to use the web services that hybris automatically creates. `GET` wouldn't be appropriate (REST-wise) for adding a product, even though technically it would still work. It's just not generally good design; GET should be only reading a resource.

Answer (score 0):

Use the existing mechanism as someone has actual thought about it.